# Juice UI - Height, MaxHeight properties not having affect

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

Educating myself about Juice UI and have an issue with some of the properties of juice:Dialog control, hopefully it is a noob thing.

Iam Using VS 2010, .net 4.0 as required, created new ASP.net empty web application to keep it simple.

I have installed Juice UI using NuGet, no issues with install.

My aspx page is below, nothing added to code behind.

I can successfully open the dialog using the button, so next step was to have a play with the different dialog properties.

In the Juice:Dialog control I have added the property **Height="300px"**. As I understand it this should open the dialog with a height of 300px. The dialog actually opens 'collapsed' ie I can't see the text at all and the dialog is sized as if you had resized it using the resizing handle to it's minimum height.

What am I missing here?

**Edit : Ok if I put**

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ height: 500 });
```

**in the click event I can set the size when my button clicked. So this must mean the properties of the dialog control are only relevant if AutoOpen=True ie the dialog opens on the initial page load. Am I close?**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employees.aspx.cs" Inherits="JuiceSkeleton.Employees" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <button id="accept" runat="server" class="open-dialog" type="button">
        Accept</button>
    <juice:Button ID="acceptButton" runat="server" TargetControlID="accept" />
</div>
<div id="dialog" class="basic-dialog" runat="server">
    <p>
        Default Dialog says No!
    </p>
</div>
<juice:Dialog Draggable="True" ID="dialogButton" Height="300px" runat="server" TargetControlID="dialog"
    AutoOpen="False" />
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 // Respond to the click 
 $(".open-dialog").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // Open the dialog 
     $(".basic-dialog").dialog("open");
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the property only takes a numeric value. However, because jQuery UI Dialog accepts "auto" as a value, we had to make the property type dynamic to accept numbers and "auto". Dropping the "px" unit decl. from your value will give you the correct output.

However, due to a problem with internal code, this will throw an exception in the current version.

The issue has been tracked here, https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/issues/23, and a fix has already been committed. The next maintenance release will contain this fix. At the moment, your workaround using javascript will work just fine. When the next release is out, you'll be able to use that property as per usual.

Comment: Ok, I did drop the px previously and got "Ambiguous match found" error. This is probably the error you are talking about? I can proceed for now but look forward to the update. Thanks very much for the speedy response. I am only just looking at JQuery after a break from web development but it is going to be fantastic as it evolves, a real time saver.

_Hey, just had a look at that issue on gitHub. It mentions Height specifically but I think there is an issue with Width, MaxHeight, MinHeight (these are the properties I was playing with)_

Comment: Please add a comment on the issue and I'll make sure those all get addressed.

Comment: I don't have a login to Github if that is what you mean.